# DKIM Key in Sandbox

Tags: email

I am attempting to use a Production DKIM Key in a sandbox. According to documentation, we can no longer import a DKIM into a sandbox. So I intend to make the DKIM from scratch in the sandbox, with a new unique name (ie SalesforceSANDBOX) and using the same Domain name (ie company.com).

And so if I do that and have the new unique name put into our DNS system will Salesforce automatically assign the same keys (public and private) over to my sandbox ?

This is what I'm using to research :
[DKIM Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351388&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

> Since DKIM keys can no longer be imported from one organization to
> another, if DKIM is implemented in a sandbox, the keys would have to
> be recreated following a sandbox refresh and the resulting CNAME
> record would have to be published to the DNS again.

The sandbox keys can be for the same domain, but the selectors (and therefore the DNS entries) will need to be unique.

I can confirm this does work fine, and each instance can send DKIM signed emails with the same domain.